# How to read the file from backward and put into the other files

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a file in which data block is separated by line and I want to read the file from bottom and want to accomplish copy and paste the last batch and 2nd last batch details separated with delimiter into 2 new files.
e.g
Input File - ignore the blank line I put the blank line just to make it more readable.

```
MD     2       0  adfa adfa adfa
MD1234 john PhoneNbr otherdetails
MD4567 john2 PhoneNbr otherdetails

MD     2       0  adfa adfa adfa
12345  Sam  Phonenbr otherdetails
7890   Sam2 Phonenbr otherdetails

MD     2       0  adfa adfa adfa              -- 2nd last batch
MD09876 read1 Phonenbr otherdetails
MDb9870 read2 Phonenbr otherdetails

MD     2       0  adfa adfa adfa             --- last batch 
12395  Sam4 Phonenbr otherdetails
78908  Sam5 Phonenbr otherdetails
```

Output: I want last batch and second last batch in two different files.

- `1.txt` — Last batch excluding the delimiter line ( ^MD    2)

  ```
  12395  Sam4 Phonenbr otherdetails
  78908  Sam5 Phonenbr otherdetails
  ```
- `2.txt` — Second last batch excluding the delimiter line ( ^MD    2)

  ```
  MD09876 read1 Phonenbr otherdetails
  MDb9870 read2 Phonenbr otherdetails
  ```

I have written the script to do that.  Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Reverse the file from bottom to up -- `sed '1!G;h;$!d'`
2. Then read the from top.
3. create the new files with those data.

but that seems not the good way.

Can you please help with any awk, sed command ??

Comment: Do you want with sed, awk or other ways are fine?

Comment: Besides using sed to reverse the file, there is a command just for that purpose: `tac`

Answer (score 2):

Just use a 2-pass approach, first to count how many records are in the file and then to write to the appropriate file name:

```
awk '
/^MD[[:space:]]/ {
    isHdr = 1
}

NR==FNR {
    if (isHdr) {
        numRecs++
        isHdr = 0
    }
    next
}

{
    if (isHdr) {
        numRecs--
        isHdr = 0
    }
    else {
        print > ((numRecs+1) ".txt")
    }
}
' file file
```

If you only want to print the last 2 (or 50 or whatever number you like) records then just adjust to test for the record numbers, i.e.:

```
awk '
/^MD[[:space:]]/ {
    isHdr = 1
}

NR==FNR {
    if (isHdr) {
        numRecs++
        isHdr = 0
    }
    next
}

{
    if (isHdr) {
        numRecs--
        isHdr = 0
    }
    else if (numRecs < 2) {
        print > ((numRecs+1) ".txt")
    }
}
' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re '/^MD\s+2/{x;s/.*\n\n(.*($|\n\n.*))/\1/;x};H;$!d;x;h;s/[^\n]*\n(.*)\n\n.*/\1/w file2' -e 'x;s/.*\n\n[^\n]*\n//w file1' -e 'd' file0
```

This reads through the file once storing the last two data blocks in the hold space. At end of file, it writes the penultimate block to file2 and the last block to file1.